# ViewPager PageTransformation issue

Tags: android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I'm using Vertical ViewPager with Velocity and Fling effect in it giving a 3d view. The issue that i'm facing is:
i-  PageTransformation doesn't apply on calling notifydatasetchanged until i touch the viewpager and scroll it a bit.
ii- While user is scrolling the list and i add new items in pager using pagination, the user feels a jerk. I know that PagerAdapter doesn't support any other method than 'notifydatasetchanged'. But can it be improved?
 Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately couldn't find a proper way.